# How do I handle multiple string delimeters in a major mode?

Tags: major-mode, font-lock, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to write a major mode for a language that supports normal strings and triple-quoted strings (`"foo"` and `"""foo"""`).

```el
(defconst my-string-mode-syntax-table
  (let ((table (make-syntax-table)))
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\" "\"" table)
    table))

(defconst my-string-mode-triple-quoted
  (rx "\"\"\"" (group (*? anything) "\"\"\"")))

(define-derived-mode my-string-mode prog-mode "My Mode"
  "testing"
  :syntax-table my-string-mode-syntax-table
  (set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-defaults)
       `(((,my-string-mode-triple-quoted 1 'font-lock-string-face t))))
  (font-lock-fontify-buffer))
```

I've marked `"` as a string delimiter, and highlighted triple-quoted strings.

This works in some cases:

```
"""foo "bar" baz"""
```

However, string highlighting is broken when I have an odd number of double quotes:

```
 """foo " bar"""
```

It also breaks `parse-partial-sexp` as it no longer returns strings in the correct places.

What's the correct emacs functionality to handle this?

Comment: A fast (but possibly not very helpful) hint would be to check out python-mode.el, since Python supports this syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `syntax-propertize-function` or `font-lock-syntactic-keywords`.

Here's a simple example:

```
(defconst my-string-mode-syntax-table
  (make-syntax-table))

(defconst my-string-mode-triple-quoted
  (rx (group "\"") (group "\"\"" (*? anything) "\"\"") (group "\"")))

(define-derived-mode my-string-mode prog-mode "My Mode"
  "testing"
  :syntax-table my-string-mode-syntax-table
  (set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-syntactic-keywords)
       (list
        `(,my-string-mode-triple-quoted
          (1 "\"")
          (2 ".")
          (3 "\"")
          )))
  (font-lock-fontify-buffer))
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to setup a `syntax-propertize-function`.
As Patrick Steele suggests, you can look for an existing example in python.el.